# Importing Haskell modules

Tags: haskell, leksah

I'm new to Haskell.  How come when I try to use `Days` from `Data.Time` I get this error:

```
Could not find module `Data.Time':
      It is a member of the hidden package `time-1.1.4'.
      Perhaps you need to add `time' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
```

I am importing Data.List and Control.Monad, and neither gives me this error message, but the code `import Data.Time` does.

What am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:  I'm getting a similar error message when I use: `import Directory`

Thanks guys, your answers got me on track!

Comment: From the error message, I assume you're using cabal to build your project.  In that case, you need to list the packages your project depends on in its cabal file.  I think the syntax is something like "build-depends: time, directory"; I'm sure someone here will know the exact syntax if that's not it.

Comment: I've been using Leksah.  Maybe its using Cabal behind the scenes and I need to manually configure the build???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fire up Leksah with this project, open the package menu and select "edit package" from it. Now, choose "dependencies" and add the dependency you need (in your case `time`). You may also choose a version.

PS: Don't forget to hit the "save" button afterwards. (I think this is a design failure...).

Answer (score 4):

Just edit the projects `.cabal` file, usually in the top directory named `ProjectName.cabal` and find the line(s) with "build-depends:" and add "time" to this list.  No need for Leksah, unless you already use it.

EDIT: To answer your question of "why now and not with module X"

Data.Time is in the `time` package, which evidently isn't included in your build dependencies.  Similar story for the `Directory` module.  You don't get these errors with `Data.List` or `Control.Monad` because they are part of the `base` package which I'll bet is in your build-deps.

On a side note, it is worth taking time to learn what modules are in `base` and what functionality those modules provide.  Base is rather large and very useful.