# importing lib in haskell after installing with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, leksah

Excuse the simplicity of this question, but I didn't find another question that addressed my issue.  I have installed haskell and leksah, then performed "cabal install nat" to install the natural numbers lib.  The lib looks like it was installed in "/Users/jstanford/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.0.4/lib/nat-0.2/lib"

I created a workspace and a package in leksah, and updated my prefs to look in:

/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework
/Users/jstanford/Library/Haskell
/Users/jstanford/.leksah-0.10/packageSources

for package sources and left the default ~/.leksah-0.10/packageSources for unpacking cabal packages.

I grabbed the first snippets of code from "Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design", so my code looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Module      :  Main
-- Copyright   :
-- License     :  AllRightsReserved
--
-- Maintainer  :
-- Stability   :
-- Portability :
--
-- |
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

module Main (
    main
) where

import Data.List ((\\))
import GHC.Arr (accumArray, elems, Array(..))



minfree :: [Nat] -> Nat
minfree xs = head([0 ..])\\ xs

search :: Array Int Bool -> Int
search = length takeWhile id . elems

checklist :: [Int] -> Array Int Bool
checklist xs = accumArray(V) False (0,n)
               (zip (filter (<= n) xs) (repeat True))
               where n = length xs

main = (

    minfree[0, 2, 5]
    )
```

Leksah was able to find the imports for \ and Array, but can't find Nat.  Any pointers on how to find the import?  The compiler also complains about accumArray(V).  I suspect that V is not really supposed to be the capital letter V, rather some symbol that looks like a V.  Guidance on that would be very much appreciated as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Nat` type is defined in [`Data.Number.Nat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/nat/latest/doc/html/Data-Number-Nat.html), so you should import it at the top of your file:

```
import Data.Number.Nat
```

As for the `(V)`, it's probably meant to be `(||)`. The "V" is most likely ∨, the symbol for logical disjunction: more commonly known as the boolean *or* operator. Operator substitutions like this are common in typeset Haskell code, but can be quite confusing until you get used to seeing them.

Additionally, you shouldn't import the array functions from `GHC.Arr`; that's an internal GHC module; I recommend importing [`Data.Array`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array.html) instead.

Comment: I had to add nat to the package dependencies.  This question also helped:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170426/importing-haskell-modules